# How to find the general formula of an arithmetic progression?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, combinations

[image]

I'm very new to combinatorics and graph theory and I was doing some work and I was asked to find certain values which I tabulated above.

The table follows this general pattern and continues along.

My problem is this;

How do I go about solving for the **GENERAL FORMULA** of tables of values such as this?

**OBSERVATION**

I've made some deductions and with respect to the $D_1 \quad D_2 .....$ values etc

So what I first did was collect ALL the values of $D_1$ in terms of $V$ and then $D_2$ in terms of $V$ etc until I reached $D_8$

The reason for focusing on the '$V$' value is that the graph theory work used to find the respective $D$ values is dependent upon $V$ , where $V$ denotes the vertex of the graph

So for example $D_1 = V -1$

$D_2 = (V) + (V+1) + (V+2) + (V+3) + (V+4) + (V+5)....$

$D_3 = (V-1) + (V+1) + (V+3) + (V+5) +(V +7) + (V+9) ....$

And I did this all the way till $D_8$

Is this the correct method to try and find a formula to solve for the SB value ,assuming that this is a method , what do I need to do next?

I need to find a formula such that when I enter the value of the vertex and edge I am able to compute the SB value in all cases.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of what I need to do to achieve this?

Is there any software that computes such a formula?

What are some recommended reading materials to help me better solve these kinds of problems?

The only book that I currently used is the Graph theory by Harary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your pattern seems to be that when $V = n+1$, $D_n = n$, and then it increases by $n$ each time. In other words, when $V = n+k$, $D_n = kn$; or, in terms of $V$ directly, $D_n = (V-n)n = nV - n^2$.

The SB column is the sum $D_1 + D_2 + \dots + D_{V-1}$, giving us
$$
   \sum_{n=1}^{V-1} D_n = \sum_{n=1}^{V-1} (nV - n^2) = V \sum_{n=1}^{V-1} n - \sum_{n=1}^{V-1}n^2. 
$$
The first sum is the sum $1 + 2 + \dots + (V-1)$ and such sums are easy to compute: the values are uniformly spaced, and so we can take the average value (which is $\frac V2$) and multiply it by the number of terms (which is $V-1$). We get $\frac{V(V-1)}{2}$ for the first sum, or $\frac{V^2(V-1)}{2}$ when you take the factor of $V$ in front into account.

The second sum is the sum $1^2 + 2^2 + \dots + (V-1)^2$, and this is trickier to compute. But there's a well-known formula for this sum: $$1^2 + 2^2 + \dots + (V-1)^2 = \frac{V(V-1)(2V-1)}{6}.$$ If you know the formula, then it can be verified using induction.

Putting these together, we get
$$
   D_1 + D_2 + \dots + D_{V-1} = \frac{V^2(V-1)}{2} - \frac{V(V-1)(2V-1)}{6} = \frac{V(V-1)}{2} \cdot \left(V - \frac{2V-1}{3}\right) = \frac{(V+1)V(V-1)}{6}.
$$
So that gives you the answer.

However, since the formula we got is just a different way of writing $\binom{V+1}{3}$, you should see if there's a more direct argument for the thing you're counting: whatever it is, maybe you can interpret it as picking $3$ things out of $V+1$?

Comment: Please clarify the following for me if you can
1.The sum 1+2+.... + (V - 1) which you obtained did you get by summing the first column of $D_1$ ? Or was this done by summing the first row to obtain the first SB value?

2. Also when getting the second sum did you sum along the $D_2$ column? I'm just a little confused where exactly you are computing $1^{2} + 2^{2} + ... + (V - 1)^{2}$

Is the methodology one where you try to find a pattern along the rows and then compute the first two , as you have done , and then this will give a general formula? 
@MishaLavrov

Comment: Once we have found a formula for $D_n$, we split up the sum $D_1 + D_2 + \dots + D_{V-1}$ into two parts. Since $D_n = nV - n^2$, we can first compute the sum of $nV$, and then subtract the sum of $n^2$. This doesn't correspond to any row or column in your table exactly.

Comment: Ok , thanks for clearing that up for me  

I have tried using the formula $\displaystyle\frac{(V+1) V (V-1)}{6}$ to solve the SB value of a similar problem with the same pattern but it does not yield the same results , is there something that I'm missing from the equation?[See link attached]  

For example to find $D_4$ , $D_4 = 4 \times k$ and $ 7 = 4 + k$  

So $k=3$ and $D_4 = 4 \times 3 = 12$ , So it works!  

but , using the formula gives $\displaystyle\frac{(7)(6)(5)}{6} = 35 $ which is not equal to SB value of 29 for row 1  
https://imgur.com/a/dIIzQjX @MishaLavrov

Comment: Uh, yes, if you change the numbers in the table, the formula will stop working...